# Delete Records with Whitespace - MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-delete

I have records such as the following:

```
+----+----------+
| id | word     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | abc123   |
+----+----------+
| 2  | abc 123  |
+----+----------+
| 3  | xyz12 3  |
+----+----------+
| 4  | xyz123   |
+----+----------+
| 5  |  aaa 444 |
+----+----------+
| 6  | aaa444   |
+----+----------+
```

**Q** How can I delete the records with a space in them? That means that records 2, 3, and 5 would be deleted.

Comment: do you worry about first *space* or last *space* character as well?

Comment: Yes, any space at the beginning, middle, or end should trigger a delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regex required, just a global match on either side of a space:

`delete from table where word like '% %';`

word is the column you defined, and table is the table word is a column of.